# Two related enums mapping?

Tags: java, enums

I have two enums which are related.

Enum1:

```
public enum HttpMethodName 
{
    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE; 
}
```

Enum2:

```
public enum ProtocolOperation {
    CREATE(1), RETRIEVE(2), UPDATE(3), DELETE(4), NOTIFY(5);


    private BigInteger operationId;

    public BigInteger getOperationId() {
        return operationId;
    }

    private ProtocolOperation(int operationId) {
        this.operationId = BigInteger.valueOf(operationId);
    }
}
```

The enums values have mapping as:

```
Create--> POST
Retrieve--> GET
Update--> PUT
Delete--> DELETE
Notify---> POST
```

So there is one to one mapping between values except only for `POST` case which can have two values either `Create` or `Notify` based on a condition.

I was thinking of keeping the mapping as `List`:

```
    public enum HttpMethodName 
    {

        POST(new List(ProtocolOperation.CREATE, ProtocolOperation.NOTIFY)) ,GET ( new List(ProtocolOperation.RETRIEVE) ) ,
PUT (new List(ProtocolOperation.UPDATE) ,DELETE(new List(ProtocolOperation.DELETE) ;

        List<ProtocolOperation > ops;
        HttpMethodName (List<ProtocolOperation> ops)
        {
            this.ops = ops;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better approach??

**EDIT:**

I will want mapping **both** ways from `HttpMethodName <----> ProtocolOperation`

Comment: Was that last edit to make the word "both" bold, a reaction to my answer? Because my answer has mapping in both directions.

Comment: use can use BiMap in Guava

Comment: Are you expecting to have two `Map` instances, or are the existing answers recommending methods good enough? Perhaps you can also share how will this relationship be used further in your codebase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you find your current approach unsatisfactory?

Without the knowledge of your concerns I can only suggest to remove boilerplate:

```
import static ProtocolOperation.*;

public enum HttpMethodName {
    GET(RETRIEVE),
    POST(CREATE, NOTIFY),
    PUT(UPDATE),
    DELETE(ProtocolOperation.DELETE);

    final List<ProtocolOperation> ops;

    HttpMethodName(ProtocolOperation... ops) {
        this.ops = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(ops));
    }
}
```

## UPD:

If you want to have mapping in both ways, it makes sense to hardcode mapping from `ProtocolOperation` to `HttpMethodName` first (as it doesn't require list) and create a simple search method in `MttpMethodName`:

```
public enum ProtocolOperation {
    CREATE(1, HttpMethodName.POST),
    RETRIEVE(2, HttpMethodName.GET),
    UPDATE(3, HttpMethodName.PUT),
    DELETE(4, HttpMethodName.DELETE),
    NOTIFY(5, HttpMethodName.POST);

    private BigInteger operationId;
    private HttpMethodName methodName;

    public BigInteger getOperationId() {
        return operationId;
    }

    public HttpMethodName getMethodName() {
        return methodName;
    }

    private ProtocolOperation(int operationId, HttpMethodName httpMethodName) {
        this.methodName = httpMethodName;
        this.operationId = BigInteger.valueOf(operationId);
    }
}

public enum HttpMethodName {
    GET,
    POST,
    PUT,
    DELETE;

    List<ProtocolOperation> getProtocolOperations() {
        List<ProtocolOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ProtocolOperation>(2);
        for (ProtocolOperation op : ProtocolOperation.values()) {
            if (op.getMethodName() == this) {
                ops.add(op);
            }
        }
        return ops;
    }
}
```

As you have constant and small number of values, you don't need to create final static map in `HttpMethodName` to provide the backwards mapping, linear search is fast enough for your case.

Comment: Since OP wants a map from `ProtocolOperation` to `HttpMethodName`, you should have done it the other way, which would also eliminate the need for a list.

Comment: @Andreas: That would lead to iterating of enum values every time to find the mapping ??

Comment: @Andreas, what makes you think that OP wants mapping from `ProtocolOperation` to `HttpMethodName`? Judging from his words `The enums values have mapping as: `  and the following table I would assume that he wants map from `HttpMethodName` to `ProtocolOperation`.

Comment: I will want mapping from both sides. i am editing the question

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha I updated my answer to cover mapping in both ways.

Answer (score 4):

Create the mapping from `ProtocolOperation` to `HttpMethodName` like you showed with the arrows, so they are simple references, not lists.

The reverse mapping can then be a static method that iterates the 5 enum values for matches. There are only 5 values, so a sequential search is adequately fast, unless it's something you do in a very tight loop, and that's unlikely in this case. Besides, you shouldn't code for performance until a profiler says you have a problem.

You follow the mappings as follows:

```
// From ProtocolOperation to HttpMethodName
HttpMethodName method = ProtocolOperation.CREATE.getHttpMethodName();

// From HttpMethodName to ProtocolOperation
ProtocolOperation op = ProtocolOperation.forMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
```

Implementation:

```
public enum HttpMethodName 
{
    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE; 
}
public enum ProtocolOperation {
    CREATE  (1, HttpMethodName.POST),
    RETRIEVE(2, HttpMethodName.GET),
    UPDATE  (3, HttpMethodName.PUT),
    DELETE  (4, HttpMethodName.DELETE),
    NOTIFY  (5, HttpMethodName.POST);

    private final int            operationId;
    private final HttpMethodName httpMethodName;

    private ProtocolOperation(int operationId, HttpMethodName httpMethodName) {
        this.operationId = operationId;
        this.httpMethodName = httpMethodName;
    }

    public int getOperationId() {
        return this.operationId;
    }

    public HttpMethodName getHttpMethodName() {
        return this.httpMethodName;
    }

    public static List<ProtocolOperation> forMethod(HttpMethodName httpMethodName) {
        List<ProtocolOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ProtocolOperation op : values())
            if (op.httpMethodName == httpMethodName)
                ops.add(op);
        return ops;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I posted the same solution as you. This was not intentional. Upvoting you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with separating logic from enum. Your approach is a tight coupling, less elastic. With such library with transform metod you are more flexible

```
private static final Map<HttpMethodName , ProtocolOperation> mapping = new HashMap<>();
static {
mapping .put(Create, POST);
// rest of methods
}
```

And here the body of your mapping method (I am using Jdk8):

```
public static Optional<HttpMethodName > map(ProtocolOperation  op){
 if (!mapping.containsKey(op)){
   return Optional.empty();
 }
  return Optional.of(mapping.get(op));
}
```

In short: enum should not have any business logic associated with them, for mapping and transformation there should be used external methods (utils).

**UPDATE**:
As @Andreas has correctly pointed, in this particular example, where mapping is fixed, and should not be extended, you can stay with his way of initializing:

```
 HttpMethodName(ProtocolOperation... ops) {
    this.ops = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(ops));
 }
```

Comment: Why do you thing that enum should not contain mapping? For me, relation between HTTP methods and their roles is set in stone by HTTP protocol. You'd be right if there were several (say, more than two) different mappings involving `HttpMethodName` enum, but I find it to be unlikely.

Comment: Few years later I was doing same approach. In this example it may have sence, but generally we tend to keep the code open for extensions. Having mappings in a utility class will enable us to create separate mappings for other clients/modules, etc. But I must admit that in this example, keeping list of enums insode of an enum can be good.