# Using Java 8 Streams how to convert an Array of Enum Objects to an other Enum Array

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using Java 8 Streams how to convert an Array of Enum Objects to an other Enum Object Array

**Class Structure**

```
 enum QUESTIONS {
        CONTACT_QUESTION,
        ADDRESS_QUESTION,
        WORK_QUESTION
    };

 enum CODES {
       CQ,
       AQ,
       WQ
    };
```

**INPUT**

```
CODES[] firstSet_Short = {CODES.CQ, CODES.AQ}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
QUESTIONS[] firstSet_Long = {QUESTIONS.CONTACT_QUESTION, QUESTIONS.ADDRESS_QUESTION}
```

Comment: What's the background/context for that _mapping_ ? Seems there's a better solution in surrounding design than solving by streaming.

Comment: context is api-of-backend returns a enum of  codes(shorter ones) while the frontend need an enum of questions(longer version)

Comment: Possibly related/dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709686/two-related-enums-mapping

Answer (score 1):

Here I am matching the initials of the codes like `C***_Q***`:

```
CODES[] firstSet_Short = {CODES.CQ, CODES.AQ};

List<QUESTIONS> result = Arrays.stream(firstSet_Short)
        .map(c -> Arrays.stream(QUESTIONS.values())
                .filter(q -> q.toString().matches(c.toString().charAt(0) + ".+_" + c.toString().charAt(1) + ".+"))
                .findFirst().orElse(null))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); //or .toArray(QUESTIONS[]::new); if you want array

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
[CONTACT_QUESTION, ADDRESS_QUESTION]
```

---

A better way would be to store a mapping in `CODES` like this:

```
enum CODES {
    CQ(QUESTIONS.CONTACT_QUESTION),
    AQ(QUESTIONS.ADDRESS_QUESTION),
    WQ(QUESTIONS.WORK_QUESTION);

    private QUESTIONS question;

    CODES(QUESTIONS question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public QUESTIONS getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
}
```

And then your code will become:

```
QUESTIONS[] result = Arrays.stream(firstSet_Short)
        .map(CODES::getQuestion)
        .toArray(QUESTIONS[]::new);
```

Comment: The solution suggested latter, should be the way one could say, since the server as mentioned by OP could then be sending `AMAZNING_QUESTION` and clients can still represent it as `AQ`. But maybe they might be looking for a reversed mapping in my opinion.